# Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported, when i try send JSON to Spring

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, rest

When i send JSON package from jQuery to Spring RestController i have many errors:

In Spring:

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

in Chrome:

> POST http://localhost/post 415
>
> (anonymous)   @   main.js:11

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#go').on('click', function() {

    var user = {
        "name" : "Tom",
        "age" : 23
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/post",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true
    });

   });

 });
```

My Spring RestController code:

```
@RestController
public class mainController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Object> postUser(@RequestBody User user){
System.out.println(user);
return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getStr(){
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    return new User("Tom", 56); //'Get' Check
}

}
```

Entity User:

```
@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
  private String name;
  private int age;
}
```

Comment: `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: The backend is expecting `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` as Content-Type, you're sending `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`.  You should check the backend logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using wrong mediatype i.e `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE` for consume in rest conttroller. Use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` as you are passing json request.

```
@RestController
public class mainController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Object> postUser(@RequestBody User user){
System.out.println(user);
return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getStr(){
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    return new User("Tom", 56); //'Get' Check
}

}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, you save me. May i ask one more question, how can i send a file in POST request in my Backend?

Comment: You can use `FormData` to pass data from ajax and use `MultipartFile` to fetch data at backend. Here is a  good article on this https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example-ajax-and-rest/